# How can I disable powerlevel10k (p10k) temporarily in a shell

Tags: shell, configuration, zsh

I want to just do something simple, turn off p10k for a couple minutes for some screenshots.  I thought the simplest thing to do would be just `export PS1='$ '`.  But apparently p10k is doing something more complicated.

```
   09:07:00 ~/git/gcloud-k8s main !1 ?4                         
   ❯ echo $PS1 | cut -c 1-40
   ${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}%{${_p9k__raw_m
   }:-${${${_p9k__m:#-*}:+${${_p9k__1g+${(p
   }}}${_p9k__2-${_p9k__2l-${${:-${_p9k__bg
   09:07:10 ~/git/gcloud-k8s main !1 ?4                         
   ❯ export PS2=fred
   09:07:40 ~/git/gcloud-k8s main !1 ?4                         
   ❯ echo $PS2 | cut -c 1-40
   fred
   09:07:45 ~/git/gcloud-k8s main !1 ?4                         
   ❯ export PS1='$ '
   09:08:05 ~/git/gcloud-k8s main !1 ?4                         
   ❯ echo $PS1 | cut -c 1-40
   ${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}%{${_p9k__raw_m
   }:-${${${_p9k__m:#-*}:+${${_p9k__1g+${(p
   }}}${_p9k__2-${_p9k__2l-${${:-${_p9k__bg
```

It doesn't seem to let me set PS1 (or resets it continuously).  Is there a simple way to just turn it off for the current shell?

Comment: Just running a subshell `zsh --no-rcs` sort of gets the desired result, but then all my other zsh customizations disappear, which I've grown dependent on.

Comment: Which zsh version supports `--no-rcs`? This option is not listed in my zsh man page (zsh 5.8).

Comment: `-f    equivalent to --no-rcs`, for `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)` @user1934428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how it's being sourced, for example if you're using OMZ then the process might be different. However, commenting out the line that sources it is a sure way to disable it. i.e. You can disable by removing all references to `"powerlevel10k"` and `"p10k"` from wherever it's being sourced. (e.g `~/.zshrc`)

On top of that, there seem to be a hook you can use to teardown p10k for zplugin:

```bash
# Hook for zplugin.
powerlevel10k_plugin_unload() { prompt_powerlevel9k_teardown; }
```

See: [powerlevel10k/internal/p10k.zsh #L9277](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/2aa16c54314f175e4f34fdd7fa1bdb03f1797c6a/internal/p10k.zsh#L9277)

Comment: Yeah, I get that I can disable it in my .zshrc, I just wanted something quick (and was confused by how setting PS1 didn't do the job).  

OK, this is good enough, `powerlevel10k_plugin_unload; PS1='$ '` works. (`exec zsh` to reset the current shell if I care)

Comment: Interestingly, I asked chatgpt the original question, it says run `p10k disable` (WRONG, no such thing) and then after a few more back and forths suggests I just do something simpler, `In that case, you can try manually resetting your prompt to a simpler PS1 prompt by running the following command: PS1='$ '`